# Regex in JavaScript replace function break script after uglifyjs or minify run

Tags: javascript, regex

Could someone with more regex experience than me help me out?

```
return path.replace(/\//g, '.').replace(/^\./, '');
```

I have found this regex in a js file within a giant app. The JS when run through npm node-minify or any of the others sees it as a comment and turns it into this:

```
return path.replace(/\g, '.').replace(/^\./, '');
```

I get the first bit is replacing all \ with a .  and the second bit trims any leading . from the string. Can i change this so the regex pattern is wrapped in quotes?

Comment: Sounds like a huge bug in the minifier.

Comment: But if you want to replace every \, looks like your regex is invalid. Should be `/\\/g`.

Comment: @Kinduser: The regexes (before minification) are both perfectly valid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wait, but... why?

Comment: @kinduser: Why would they be invalid?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder His regex removes every /, not \.

Comment: @Kinduser: I didn't say it did what his text says it does. I said it was valid. It (the first one) replaces `/`, not ``\``, but it's a perfectly valid regex the minifier shouldn't screw up.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder He wrote that he wants to get rid of every \. But actually his regex removes every /. Isn't his regex invalid then?

Comment: @Kinduser: No. "Invalid" means it's not a valid regex. It could be *incorrect*, but it's not at all clear from the question that the user means it to replace ``\``. All he said was *"I get that the first bit is replacing..."* which is far from saying that's what he wants it to do.

Comment: Guys sorry, i inherited this javascript and as i said i aint no regex king. But when i run the script through uglifyjs the app breaks. When i run it through https://www.npmjs.com/package/strip-comments  i get a warning in phpsorm on this line and the line is above. So when i said "I get the first bit is replacing all \ "  it was actually by guess... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor and quote your pattern.

```js
const path = '/usr/bin/env';
const matchSlash = new RegExp('/', 'g');
const translate = path => path.replace(matchSlash, '.').replace(/^\./, '');
console.log(translate(path));
```

Comment: I think you want `new RegExp('/', 'g');` there instead (I think the point is to remove the double forward slash that looks like a comment to the minifier: "//")